# Which is more precise? 328.4 or 0.0008?

Tags: significant-figures

What is more precise? 328.4 or 0.0008?

I want to know if precision is based on the number of significant figures or the number of places past the decimal?

Comment: It depends, if you are interested in absolute or relative precision. Also, precision is related to uncertainty of the value, otherwise, it is rather related to  resolution.

Comment: Questions about significant figures and dimensional analysis in general are off-topic on Chemistry.SE, unless they are chemistry-related. From [Meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/472): "*Questions about dimensional analysis that do not refer to a specific chemistry question or problem should be closed. They can be migrated to mathematics.se as they allow such kinds of questions in their [homework policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).*"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because general questions about numerical analysis are off-topic on Chemistry.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 328.4 has 4 significant figures. It is very precise.

The number 0.008 has only one significant figure. It is not precise at all.

In order to define the precision, the number of zeros necessary for representing the first significant figure, does not count. This number depends on the unit. For example, 0.0008 kg is as precise as 0.8 g. Both values have the same level of precision : one significant figure.